How to run ptpython on Windows 11 in asyncio mode
I have Windows 11 and Python 3.12.3 and wish to experiment with the asyncio REPL.  It works fine with the built-in REPL:
PS C:\> python -m asyncio
asyncio REPL 3.12.3 (tags/v3.12.3:f6650f9, Apr  9 2024, 14:05:25) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Use "await" directly instead of "asyncio.run()".
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import asyncio
>>> await asyncio.sleep(1, 'Done!')
'Done!'
>>> exit()

However, I cannot get it to work with ptpython:
PS C:\> ptpython --asyncio

Starting ptpython asyncio REPL
Use "await" directly instead of "asyncio.run()".
In [1]: await asyncio.sleep(1, 'Done!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 183, in run_and_show_expression_async
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda *_: task.cancel())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 582, in add_signal_handler
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts\ptpython.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\ptpython\entry_points\run_ptpython.py", line 231, in run

    asyncio.run(embed_result)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete

    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 528, in coroutine

    await repl.run_async()
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 252, in run_async

    await self.run_and_show_expression_async(text)
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 206, in run_and_show_expression_async

    loop.remove_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 585, in remove_signal_handler

    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-314' coro=<PythonRepl.run_and_show_expression_async.<locals>.eval() done, defined at C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py:172> exception=NameError("name 'asyncio' is not defined")>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 175, in eval

    return await self.eval_async(text)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 329, in eval_async

    result = await result
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'asyncio' is not defined. Did you forget to import 'asyncio'

From the ptpython docs, this should work - a similar example is shown working:
https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython
How do I get ptpython to work in asyncio mode on Windows 11?
Update on 6/7/2024, 21:15 UTC - tried on Python 3.8.10 to see if only a problem on 3.12.3, similar results:
PS C:\> python -m asyncio
asyncio REPL 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:34:34) [MSC v.1928 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Use "await" directly instead of "asyncio.run()".
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import asyncio
>>> await asyncio.sleep(1, 'Done!')
'Done!'
>>> exit()

C:\> ptpython --asyncio
Starting ptpython asyncio REPL
Use "await" directly instead of "asyncio.run()".
In [1]: await asyncio.sleep(1, 'Done!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 183, in run_
and_show_expression_async
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda *_: task.cancel())
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 536, in add_signal_handler
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\users\james\appdata\local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\ptpython.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\ptpython\entry_points\run_ptpython.py", line 231, in run
    asyncio.run(embed_result)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 528, in coroutine
    await repl.run_async()
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 252, in run_async
    await self.run_and_show_expression_async(text)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 206, in run_and_show_expression_async
    loop.remove_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 539, in remove_signal_handler
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-61' coro=<PythonRepl.run_and_show_expression_async.<locals>.eval() done, defined at c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py:172> exception=NameError("name 'asyncio' is not defined")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 175, in eval
    return await self.eval_async(text)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\ptpython\repl.py", line 329, in eval_async
    result = await result
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'asyncio' is not defined

Note - the async REPL was added in 3.8:
https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#asyncio
Update on 6/12/2024, 16:36 UTC - work around from @jupiterbjy:
PS C:\> ptpython
>>> import asyncio
>>> async def main():
  2   return await asyncio.sleep(1, 'Done!')
  3
>>> print(asyncio.run(main()))
Done!
>>> exit()


From the ptpython githib page: "Ptpython is an advanced Python REPL. It should work on all Python versions from 2.6 up to 3.11 and work cross platform (Linux, BSD, OS X and Windows).
Note: this version of ptpython requires at least Python 3.6. Install ptpython 2.0.5 for older Python versions."
You're using 3.12.  Are you sure it's supported?

@PaulCornelius Good question - tried on 3.8 with similar results.

Use of signal handlers only works on *nix because windows doesn't use it - since we're on windows and thus is using ProactorEventLoop this probably isn't implemented. iirc had similar experience writing this answer. If you try this on WSL it will work. Seems like hindsight of ptpython.. is this issue your's btw?

@jupiterbjy Thanks, and yes - that's my issue in the ptpython repo.  I figured since no one is answering, I should open a GitHub issue.  I'm comfortable with Python but just learning async (from reading Fluent Python 2e).  I thought maybe I could use a debugger and figure out what's wrong but I don't think it's quite that straight forward with async code.  I'll spend some more time going through your examples and see if it helps me dive more into what ptpython is doing.  I can always do async in Linux through WSL/VMware Workstation too...

well you can comfortably do that in ptpython too with some inconvenience - cause I did when learning fluent python 2nd Edition back in 2019~2021 and still do time to time writing answers for SO, just by wrapping it in async func and running it. import asyncio / async def main(): / await asyncio.sleep(5) / asyncio.run(main()). I personally recommend this more as this more closely resemble how actually async code runs, not under the loop already created by REPL. There's some quarks that's invisible under REPL's loop!

@jupiterbjy Fair point with running async in the REPL "by hand"
